# How to create a Laravel Nova Gate/Policy to restrict access to Nova tools?

Tags: laravel, authorization, policy, laravel-nova

How can I create a policy/gate to restrict users from accessing Nova tools (e.g. Spatie Nova Backup Tool)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same issue and I resolved it like this.

1. Go to `NovaServiceProvider`
2. Add a gate/check in the `tools()` method

   ```
   public function tools()

   {

       if (Auth::user()->hasAnyRole(['admin'])) {
           return [new Foo, new Bar];
       }

       return [];
   }
   ```

This will solve the issue but I am not sure wether this is the `Nova` way of doing it or not.

Answer (score 5):

Doing this the "Nova way", would be using the `canSee()`-method. You can read about it [here](https://nova.laravel.com/docs/1.0/metrics/registering-metrics.html#authorization).

```
public function tools()
{
    return [
        YourToolThatMightBeHidden::make()
            ->canSee(function ($request) {
                return $request->user()->can('access-this-tool');
            }),
    ];
}
```